# Significance of echo Start|cat>>log in bash

Tags: bash, echo, pipe, cat

Can anyone help me out with the following code snippet -

```
echo Start|cat>>log
```

When I tried

```
echo Start>>log
```

it gave the same output to the log file. Can anyone explain the difference between the two commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat` is one of those programs that can take an argument and use it, or just use its standard input if you don't provide an argument. In other words, while:

```
cat xyzzy
```

will open the file `xyzzy` and output its contents, the command:

```
cat
```

on its own will read its standard input and send that to standard output.

Hence piping some output through `cat` without an argument is no different that just sending the output *without* `cat`, other than creating a superfluous process. In other words, these two are functionally identical:

```
echo xyzzy | cat
echo xyzzy
```

You can use either but the latter (for both my example above and in your question) will use one less process and a few less keystrokes. The `cat` filter on its own will simply pass the data through as-is and hence is not necessary.